# java.lang.IllegalStateException in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, exception

Description for [`java.lang.IllegalStateException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) from the Java docs:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

Is there an equivalent for [`IllegalStateException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) in the .NET-Framework?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

[`System.InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx)

> The exception that is thrown when a
>   method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

Comment: I think this is a better name for that type of exception

Comment: @user12345613 I don't. Java's `IllegalStateException` is not limited to objects nor object state. And the class name `InvalidOperationException` kind of hints that a method is not supported, but it does not hint that this is because of the state.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You are right; the name alone does not lend itself to quick and easy comprehension. I, too, would not have used (let alone known) that this exception was for object state exceptions purely by it's name without this answer (or the docs at microsoft). That is an issue with the framework. However, IllegalStateException is purely for objects and method calls according the java 7 docs located at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html and java 8 docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html